# Merge 2 data frames by concatenating vector

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, merge

I have the following 2 data frames:

```
> df1
     a c
[1,] 1 3
[2,] 2 3
[3,] 2 3
```

and

```
> df2
     b d
[1,] 7 9
[2,] 5 4
[3,] 8 4
[4,] 8 4
```

I am trying to concatenate the vectors "a" and "b" into "X" and then merge the two data frames in order to obtain the following desired result:

```
> dfX
     X c  d
[1,] 1 3  NA
[2,] 2 3  NA
[3,] 2 3  NA
[4,] 7 NA 9
[5,] 5 NA 4
[6,] 8 NA 4
[7,] 8 NA 4
```

The NAs are intentional.

I am convinced this must be possible using merge(df1,df2,by.x,by.y,all), however, despite my best efforts and research, i couldn't figure it out.

Finally, once the above is done, I'd like to sort the data frame in ascending order by the column X (so that the row [4,] 7 NA 9 ends up after row [5,] 5 NA 4) in order to obtain:

```
> dfX
     X c  d
[1,] 1 3  NA
[2,] 2 3  NA
[3,] 2 3  NA
[4,] 5 NA 4
[5,] 7 NA 9
[6,] 8 NA 4
[7,] 8 NA 4
```

I hope some of you can help me with this. This is sample data, my actual data consists of a large database where column "X" is "dates + times" (e.g. "2016-12-13 10:40:00 UTC") and columns c and d are quantities (e.g. "40,40").

Thank you very much in advance for your support.

Comment: COnvert to data.frame, place it in a `list` and use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

We place the `matrix`es in a `list`, loop through them (`lapply`), convert to `data.table` (`as.data.table`), set the 1st column name to 'X', and use `rbindlist` to rbind the datasets.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(list(df1, df2), function(x) setnames(as.data.table(x), 1, 'X')), fill=TRUE)
#   X  c  d 
#1: 1  3 NA
#2: 2  3 NA
#3: 2  3 NA
#4: 7 NA  9
#5: 5 NA  4
#6: 8 NA  4
#7: 8 NA  4
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your problems with merge() arise from the ambiguity in the data, e.g. the two identical rows in df1. So, provided your data is of the form as your examples, you could use unique() to first get rid of the duplicates and merge the minimal data frames:

```
df_target = data.frame(X = c(df1$a, df2$b))
df_target = merge(x = df_target, y = unique(df1), by.x = "X", by.y = "a", all.x = TRUE)
df_target = merge(x = df_target, y = unique(df2), by.x = "X", by.y = "b", all.x = TRUE)
df_target = df_target[order(df_target$X), ]
```

Alternatively you do away with merge() and explicitly construct the data frame:

```
df_target2 = data.frame(X = c(df1$a, df2$b),
                        c = c(df1$c, rep(NA, nrow(df2))),
                        d = c(rep(NA, nrow(df1)), df2$d))
df_target2 = df_target2[order(df_target2$X), ]
```

This is probably the safest way, as it does not rely on assumptions.